# Get int-type from 'int' string

Tags: python

In Python, given the string`'int'`, how can I get the *type* `int`? Using `getattr(current_module, 'int')` doesn't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`int` isn't part of the namespace of your current module; it's part of the `__builtins__` namespace. So you would run `getattr` on `__builtins__`.

To verify that it's a type you can just check whether it's an instance of `type`, since all types are derived from it.

```
>>> getattr(__builtins__, 'int')
<type 'int'>
>>> foo = getattr(__builtins__, 'int')
>>> isinstance(foo, type)
True
```

Comment: If you see the error like:
`'dict' object has no attribute 'int'`
use `import builtins` and then `getattr(builtins, 'int')`

Answer (score 4):

With this sort of thing, if you're expecting a limited set of types, you should use a dictionary to map the names to the actual type.

```
type_dict = {
   'int': int,
   'str': str,
   'list': list
}

>>> type_dict['int']('5')
5
```

Comment: "answered 28 secs ago"? okay, I'm leaving my answer since I use `.get` ... ***grumble***

Answer (score 1):

Try with an `eval()`:

```
>>>eval('int')
<type 'int'>
```

But be sure of what you give to `eval()`; it could be dangerous.

Comment: The string _should_ be a type, but I can't ensure that. Is there no other way to get built-in type by string?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use `eval`, you can just store a mapping from string to type in a dict, and look it up:

```
>>> typemap = dict()
>>> for type in (int, float, complex): typemap[type.__name__] = type
...
>>> user_input = raw_input().strip()
int
>>> typemap.get(user_input)
<type 'int'>
>>> user_input = raw_input().strip()
monkey-butter
>>> typemap.get(user_input)
>>>
```